# Can not able to take back up get error Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I am practicing to create procedure which take back up of all data base except system database using `Dynamic SQL` my procedure compile successfully but when i run it i get below error for each data base

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot open backup device
>   'F:\DHAVAL_BACKUP_DEMO\itmusket_StudentApp_2015_05_31_10:27:07.BAK'.
>   Operating system error 123(The filename, directory name, or volume
>   label syntax is incorrect.). Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I have also change my default database back up path by taking reference of [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/01/30/sql-server-fix-error-msg-3201-level-16-state-1-line-1-cannot-open-backup-device-operating-system-error-3the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/)

here is my database setting snap

[image]

please suggest  me way to overcome this problem..

Comment: Is F a network share or a local drive? Also, can you post the procedure with the dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file name with `:` is invalid, change them to `;`.

```
@SQL = '.....' + REPLACE(@BackupPath, ':', ';') + '....'
```